# How can I replace ionic2-super-tabs Toolbar with ion-slides pager function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Good day,

I'm currently using the following plugin for my ionic 3 project: https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs

This plugin offers a nice feature for swipeable tabs in Ionic apps. Within the documentation it shows how to hide the toolbar (which I've successfully managed to do). Now I want to be able to replace the toolbar with an `ion-slides` type feature like the `pager` to show the user that they can swipe left or right to access the other pages or rather in this case, tabs.

Here is my current code:

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { SuperTabsController } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';

import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private superTabsCtrl: SuperTabsController) {

  }

  welcomePage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage,{index: "1"})
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.superTabsCtrl.showToolbar(false);
}

}
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyPage } from '../my/my';
import { WelcomePage } from '../welcome/welcome';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {

  index = this.navParams.get('index')
  tab1Root = SettingsPage;
  tab2Root = WelcomePage;
  tab3Root = MyPage;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {

    }


}
```

**tabs.html**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyPage } from '../my/my';
import { WelcomePage } from '../welcome/welcome';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {

  index = this.navParams.get('index')
  tab1Root = SettingsPage;
  tab2Root = WelcomePage;
  tab3Root = MyPage;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {

    }


}
```

And this is the feature I would like to have to show navigation:
[image: to replace the toolbar navigation]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom element in the page that contains the `<super-tabs>` element.

Here's a quick example, modify as needed, keep in mind I didn't test this:

**HTML**

```
  <super-tabs (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)" ...>
    ...
  </super-tabs>
  <div class="pager">
    <span class="pager-dot" [class.selected]="selectedTabIndex === 0"></span>
    <span class="pager-dot" [class.selected]="selectedTabIndex === 1"></span>
    <span class="pager-dot" [class.selected]="selectedTabIndex === 2"></span>
  </div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
@Component( ... )
export class MyPage {
  // set it to the default selected tab
  selectedTabIndex: number = 0;
  onTabSelect(ev: any) {
    // forgot what this event passes, but I think the "ev" object has an "index" property
     this.selectedTabIndex = ev.index;
  }
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.pager {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  span.pager-dot {
    display: inline-block; // so we can set height + width to a span element
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 500rem; // make it round
    transition: all .3s linear; // make size transition smooth

    &.selected {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried out your solution, but nothing seems to be appearing at the bottom, in other words, the `<div class=pager">` is not showing up anything in the app, it is still blank as before

Comment: @TCRoberts sorry .. just updated the answer. You need to make that `.pager` element fixed and set it's position relative to the page

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But still nothing bro :( ??

Comment: @TCRoberts well that's how you can do it.. my code isn't tested.. Play around with the css and you'll get it right. I'm just tryina give some quick tips here, not write code for you.